# get line feeds in php mailto link

Tags: php

```
<form action="../">
<select name="myDestination"
onchange="this.form.WINDOW_NAMER.value++;
ob=this.form.myDestination;
window.open(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value
,'Window_Name'+this.form.WINDOW_NAMER.value,
    'toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=900,height=500')">


<option value="mailto:bob@bob.com?subject=test&body=Please write soon. Thank  you.">Email </option>
<input name="WINDOW_NAMER" type="HIDDEN" value="1">
</form>
</select>
```

this code opens a ms outlook new message window. works great, but!

in the body part i want to say

"Please write soon.

Thank you."

notice in my code it always ends up as, "Please write soon. Thank you." on the same line.

i have tried many things to get line breaks, but to no avail.

eg

Please write soon.  Thank you.

Please write soon. \n\n Thank you.

but no go

Comment: You should read about line ending conventions. MS uses different codings for line ends than other systems. That makes MS-Outlook behave incompatible to normal email clients. Have a try using "\r\n".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `%0D%0A` which is hex for new line:

```
<option value="mailto:bob@bob.com?subject=test&body=Please write soon.%0D%0AThank  you.">Email </option>
```

That will do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/ayCP7/

To add Carbon Copy and Blind Carbon copy use the following:

```
<option value="mailto:bob@bob.com?subject=test&body=Please write soon.%0D%0AThank  you&bcc=email@email.com&cc=email@email.com">Email </option>
```

Comment: ah HAH ... it works! i tried everything *except* the hex keys. thanks!

Comment: using this same sort of coding to pre-fill an email message, is there a way to add a bcc and an attachment?

Comment: @user2258973 Look at my edited answer. You can add a cc and bcc in the url value. I do not think you can add an attachment. My best suggestion is to add a hyperlink to the body of the email with the desired attachment.